# No converter found capable of converting from type [java.util.Set<?>] to type [java.lang.String]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using SPRING MVC 4 and Hibernate 4.5.

```
**Model:**
Public class Epic implements java.io.Serializable{

    private int IDEPIC;

    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @Size(max=200)
    private String description;
    private int priority;
    @NotNull
    private int estimation;
    private Set<PM> projetMetiers;

    public Epic() {
        this.projetMetiers = new HashSet<PM>();
    }
   // getters & setters
}
```

There is a ManyToMany relationship between Epic and PM.

```
**Mapping:**
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.model.Epic" table="Epic">
        <id name="IDEPIC" column="IDEPIC" >
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string" column="nameEpic" />
        <property name="description" type="string" column="descriptionEpic" />
        <property name="priority" type="int"  column="priorityEpic" />
        <property name="estimation" type="int"  column="estimationEpic" />
        <set name="projetMetiers" cascade="save-update" lazy="false" table="PM_Epic" >  
            <key column="IDEPIC"/>
            <many-to`enter code here`-many column="IDPM" class="com.model.PM"/>
    </set>
    </class>`enter code here`
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have addEpic.jsp and editEpic.jsp with following code snippet in it to show the list of Pms to select from when adding/editing Epic.

The `addAction` works good, I also have a converter that converts string ID to PM object.

```
**Controller:**
@RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
public String editEpic(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("epic", this.epicService.getEpicById(id));
    model.addAttribute("projets",this.pmService.listPMs());
        return "/epic/epicEdit";
}

** the converter* 
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
   binder.registerCustomEditor(PM.class, "projetMetiers", new PMEditor(pmService));
}

//PMEditor:
public class PMEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport{

    private PMService pmService;
    public PMEditor(PMService pmService) {
       this.pmService = pmService;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
         if (text.equals("0")) {
            this.setValue(null);
         } else {
             PM pm = pmService.getPMById(Integer.parseInt(text));
             this.setValue(pm);
         }
     }

     @Override
     public String getAsText() {
        PM pm = new PM();
        if (this.getValue() != null) {
           pm = (PM) this.getValue();
        }
        return "";
      }
   }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">  
    <form:label path="projetMetiers" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
        <spring:message text="Projets métiers :"/>
    </form:label>
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
        <form:select class="form-control" multiple="true" path="projetMetiers" itemLabel="name" itemValue="IDPM" > 
        </form:select>
       <springForm:errors path="projetMetiers" cssClass="error" />
    </div>
 </div>

<div class="form-group"> 
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="<spring:message text="Modifier"/>" />
</div>
```

Stacktrace:with root cause

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter   found capable of converting from type [java.util.Set<?>] to type   [java.lang.String] at
org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:313) at 
org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195) at
org.springframework.core.convert.support.CollectionToStringConverter.convert(CollectionToStringConverter.java:68) at
org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:35) at
org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:192) at
org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.formatFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:125)
```

I can't get the selected object, it seems that spring can't convert set to string. Any help please, and thanks.